# рендеринг сообщений в чате

Tags: reactjs

Есть 2 метода отправки и получения сообщений в чате, при положительном ответе от сервера я добавляю сообщения в чат.

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])

function sendMessage () {
if (value !== '') {
  api
    .sendMessage(value)
    .then(() => {
      setMessages([{ message: value, ownMessage: true }, ...messages])
      setValue('')
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(`Произошла ошибка: ${err}`))
}
```

}

```
function getMessage () {
api
  .recieveNotification()
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
    if (res !== null) {
      if (chatIdDisplayed === res.body.senderData.chatId) {
        setMessages([
          {
            message: res.body.messageData.textMessageData.textMessage,
            ownMessage: false
          },
          ...messages
        ])
        console.log(messages)
        api.deleteNotification(res.receiptId)
      } else {
        api.deleteNotification(res.receiptId)
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Уведомлений нет')
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

}

И сам рендеринг:

```
{messages.map((entry, id) => (
          <li
            key={id}
            className={`main__chat-message ${
              !entry.ownMessage ? 'main__chat-message_chat-partner' : ''
            }`}
          >
            {[entry.message, entry.ownMessage]}
          </li>
        ))}
```

Когда вводит сообщение пользователь, то все отрисовывается нормально, но когда сообщения приходят в ответ, поведение становится странным, исходящие сообщения полностью удаляются, появляется входящее, которые с каждым последующим входящим заменяется на новое...Подскажите кто знает, как исправить что бы нормально отрисовывались

Вызов getMessage:

```
useEffect(() => {
if (isData) {
  const setIntervalFunction = () => {
    setInterval(getMessage, 7000)
  }
  setIntervalFunction()
}
```

}, [isData])

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect
} = React;

function App() {
  // стейт для отображения сообщений
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])

  // стейт инпута
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')

  const makeid = () => {
    let text = ''
    const possible = 'QWER0123456789'

    for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++)
      text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length))

    return text
  }

  let varId = makeid()
  let varId2 = makeid()

  function sendMessage() {
    if (value !== '') {
      setMessages([{
          message: value,
          ownMessage: true,
          id: varId
        },
        ...messages
      ])
      setValue('')
    }
    console.log(messages)
  }

  function getMessage() {
    console.log('getMessage')
    setMessages([{
        message: 'Входящее сообщение',
        ownMessage: false,
        id: varId2
      },
      ...messages
    ])
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const setIntervalFunction = () => {
      setInterval(getMessage, 3000)
    }
    setIntervalFunction()
  }, [])

  return ( < div >
    <
    ul className = 'main__chat-container' > {
      messages.map(entry => ( <
        li key = {
          entry.id
        }
        className = {
          `main__chat-message`
        } > {
          [entry.message, entry.ownMessage]
        } <
        /li>
      ))
    } <
    /ul> < /
    div > )
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
root.render( < App / > )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: .recieveNotification() точно нет опечатки?

Comment: Нет, написал с ошибкой, но название идентично названию в api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в неверном `key`. В данном случае для ключа выбран `index` в массиве.

При добавлении вручную - добавляется в конец массива и у каждого нового элемента новый индекс.

При добавлении по событию - добавляется в начало массива, следовательно индексы элементов в старом и новом массивах перестают совпадать.

Из-за этого при рендере могут быть неожиданные результаты.

Для решения нужно выбирать `key` так, чтобы он был уникальным. Например завести поле `id` и заполнять его при добавлении элемента.

---

Кроме указанного выше недочета, есть несколько ошибок с замыканием значений.

1. генерация `id` которые используются для сообщений - значения замыкаются и используются одни и те же. Для решения достаточно перенести получение `id` в место, где создается сообщение
2. метод `getMessage` передаваемый в `setInterval` - ссылка на функцию замыкается, внутри функции замыкается значение `messages` (пустой массив) - поэтому. Решений может быть несколько: добавить getMessages в список зависимостей, использовать сеттер с коллбэком

Лучше всего не использовать внутри useEffect функции меняющиеся между рендерами, в противном случае необходимо добавлять их в список зависимостей, чтобы useEffect обновился при изменении.

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect
} = React;

function App() {
  // стейт для отображения сообщений
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])

  // стейт инпута
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')

  const makeid = () => {
    let text = ''
    const possible = 'QWER0123456789'

    for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++)
      text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length))

    return text
  }

  function sendMessage() {
    if (value !== '') {
      let varId = makeid();
      setMessages([{
          message: value,
          ownMessage: true,
          id: varId
        },
        ...messages
      ])
      setValue('')
    }
    console.log(messages)
  }

  function getMessage() {
    let varId2 = makeid();
    setMessages((oldMessages) => [{
        message: 'Входящее сообщение ' + varId2,
        ownMessage: false,
        id: varId2
      },
      ...oldMessages
    ])
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const setIntervalFunction = () => {
      setInterval(getMessage, 3000)
    }
    setIntervalFunction()
  }, [])

  return ( < div >
    <
    ul className = 'main__chat-container' > {
      messages.map(entry => ( <
        li key = {
          entry.id
        }
        data - id = {
          entry.id
        }
        className = {
          `main__chat-message`
        } > {
          [entry.message, entry.ownMessage]
        } <
        /li>
      ))
    } <
    /ul> < /
    div > )
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
root.render( < App / > )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: К сожалению, добавление id не помогло, поведение все равно странное, в массиве messages нет элементов даже если отправленные сообщения отображаются на экране, а как только получаю входящее сообщение, оно попадает в массив messages и каждое последующее его заменяет. В общем мало что поменялось с добавлением id :)

Comment: @agentx, добавь больше информации в вопрос. где и как ты вызываешь `getMessage`

Comment: добавил в оригинальное сообщение

Comment: @agentx, а isData когда меняется? Пока выглядит как обычная проблема с замыканием - внутри getMessage замкнулось значение messages без элементов

Comment: @agentx, сделай [mcve] который можно запустить

Comment: isData это грубо говоря стейт который не дает получать данные с апи пока не введены данные (token, id ). А как можно исправить проблему с замыканием?

Comment: @agentx, нужно посмотреть минимальный пример в сборе, чтобы точно сказать как исправить. Конкретно сейчас, можно добавить в зависимости `message`, чтобы замкнутая функция тоже менялась при изменении `message`.

Comment: @agentx, так же можно попробовать использовать `callback` в сеттере а не значение, и добавлять в предыдущий массив, а не просто заменять его. Сделай пример [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12004/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%a4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-stack-snippet-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-react-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-jsx) либо на каком-нибудь [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) чтобы в действии можно было увидеть

Comment: Разместил на git pages и упросил код, что бы получилось без использования api

https://agentx477.github.io/green-api-react-test/
https://github.com/AgeNtX477/green-api-react-test/blob/main/src/components/App/App.jsx

В модалке нужно просто ввести что угодно и засабмитить.
Раз в 7 секунд будет приходить "входящее сообщение", оно все ломает.
Кнопка "обновить данные" отправит сообщение вручную, при этом ничего не ломается...

Comment: @agentx, обновил ответ, действительно все дело в замыкании

Comment: Почему-то не работает все равно:( И не могу понять вот эту строчку кода в рендеринге
data - id = {
          entry.id
        }

Comment: @agentx, смотри отличие в своем коде и коде в ответе. В ответе проблемы нет. `data-id = { entry.id }` это показывает что в атрибут записывается уникальный `id` - если ты сделаешь это в примере в вопросе - будут одинаковые значения

Comment: Извиняюсь, все окей) Огромное спасибо